# Smart way to check a root

Tags: polynomials

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3+3x+5$. Let $\omega:=\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}{3}$. Verify that $\omega$ is a root of $y^3+y^2+2y-1$.

Is there some trick to do this computation quickly?

Comment: Other than “use some mathematical software”, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write that
$$
1+\alpha+\alpha^2=\frac{1-\alpha^3}{1-\alpha}
$$

But $\alpha^3 = -3\alpha-5$, so we have
$$
\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}3=\frac{2+\alpha}{1-\alpha}
$$

It's easier to calculate from here, since you can factor out the denominator and then ignore it (because the denominator won't be zero at the root).